# Upgrade Orbeon 3.8 - 4.1

Tags: xml, xhtml, orbeon, exist-db

We are using Orbeon 3.8 in a standard config with eXist database.

Is there a way tot easy upgrade the db to the new 4.1, and have the saved data (forms and data) available in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Stop Tomcat, and copy the content of the `WEB-INF/exist-data` directory (where the embedded eXist stores its data) from the version 3.8 expended war to the version 4.1 expended war, start Tomcat, and see if eXist is able to process the files you copied.
2. If eXist in 4.1 isn't able to handle the files you copied, use the eXist [Java Admin Client](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/java-admin-client.xml) to export the data from the eXist in 3.8 and then import it in the eXist in 4.1.

Also, instead of using the embedded eXist, I'd recommend that going forward you [deploy eXist separately from Orbeon Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/exist-configuration), so you can upgrade eXist and Orbeon Forms independently from each other.

Comment: Thank you Allessandro. We will try this approach. We have other deployments of Orbeon, just one left with a standard config. We normally use a persitance layer which connects Orbeon to a OpenERP database. We use Orbeon for managing patient information and product details in a healthcare environment